# Attempt at SSIS Execution Throws Invalid object name 'SSISDB.catalog.customized_logging_levels'

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I can run the SSIS package in SSMS 2014 if I set the build to SQL Server 2012, but attempting to run in SSMS 2017 v17.4 upgraded from 17.3x (didn't work there either) SQL Server version 13.0.4451.0 gives this error:

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

> Invalid object name 'SSISDB.catalog.customized_logging_levels'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 208)"

There is little info out there as to a fix.
IF I right click the SSISDB and click 'Customized Logging Levels' I get the same error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo
>   culture)    at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object
>   obj, Object[] index)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.LocalizablePropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Object
>   component)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.UITasks.PropertiesDataProvider.AddPropertyTableToDataBus()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.UITasks.PropertiesDataProvider.AddToDataBus()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.UITasks.PropertiesDataProvider.Initialize(ITaskManager
>   taskManager, IPropertyDictionary properties)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskManager.InitializeTaskFormComponent(Object
>   component, ITaskFormComponentInfo info)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskFormManager.InitializeTaskFormComponent(Object
>   component, ITaskFormComponentInfo info)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskManager.InitializeTaskFormComponents(IList`1
>   taskFromComponentsInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskFormManager.InitializeTaskFormComponents(IList`1
>   taskFromComponentsInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskManager.Initialize(String
>   moniker, IContext context, IList`1 taskFromComponents)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.TaskFormManager.Initialize(String
>   moniker, IContext context, ITaskFormInfo taskFormInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskFormFactoryService.CreateTaskFormInstance(String
>   taskFormMoniker, IContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.ActionHandlers.ShowTaskUIDialogActionHandler.RunTaskForm(IContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.ActionHandlers.DialogBasedActionHandler.RunTaskFormThread(Object
>   contextObject)
>
> ===================================
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteReader(String
>   sqlCommand, SqlCommand& command)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ExecuteSql.GetDataReader(String
>   query, SqlCommand& command)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.DataProvider.SetConnectionAndQuery(ExecuteSql
>   execSql, String query)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ExecuteSql.GetDataProvider(StringCollection
>   query, Object con, StatementBuilder sb, RetriveMode rm)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SqlObjectBase.FillData(ResultType
>   resultType, StringCollection sql, Object connectionInfo,
>   StatementBuilder sb)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SqlObjectBase.FillDataWithUseFailure(SqlEnumResult
>   sqlresult, ResultType resultType)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SqlObjectBase.BuildResult(EnumResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SqlObjectBase.GetData(EnumResult
>   erParent)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request
>   req, Object ci)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object
>   connectionInfo, Request request)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcInstance.GetInitDataReader(ISfcConnection
>   connection, Urn urn, String[] fields, OrderBy[] orderby)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcInstance.InitChildLevel(ISfcCollection
>   childColl)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcCollection`3.InitializeChildCollection(Boolean
>   refresh)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcCollection`3.EnsureCollectionInitialized()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SfcCollection`3.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.ISfcCollection.EnsureInitialized()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.Catalog.get_CustomizedLoggingLevels()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.Catalog.GetCustomLoggingLevels()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.Catalog.get_ServerCustomizedLoggingLevel()
>
> ===================================
>
> Invalid object name 'SSISDB.catalog.customized_logging_levels'. (.Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: SSIS is built on top of C# and .net framework. The error clearly tells you are missing a module and or dll file. I would highly suggest you develop SSIS using [Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt)/Visual Studio.

Comment: @clifton_h this was built in VS 2015

Comment: Then you need to add the “reference” that contains these objects to your project. See [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx).

Comment: @clifton_h thanks but that is not the issue, there is a bug in SSMS '16 +, as I stated in my question the code works in SSMS 2014 correctly. If there was a critical missing reference in the SSIS Package it would not execute there either.

Comment: Did we validate that it indeed does **NOT** exists? I see nothing in your posts that postulates this. Are you sure it visibly is in the list of libraries/references? I ask because SSIS as well as SSMS has had some love recently by Microsoft.

Comment: The problem is clearly that SSMS is referencing a SQL object that does not exist in your version of SSISDB. Probably it should check the version and not try and access this object  it if less than some version or other. So maybe a bug in SSMS. what version is the Sql Server instance hosting SSISDB? And was it upgraded from a previous version?

Comment: @MartinSmith edited post to answer

Comment: 13.0.4451.0 Is SQL Server 2016. Was the instance upgraded from a previous version? Have you seen this? http://panigorthi.blogspot.com.es/2017/06/invalid-object-name-ssisdbcatalogcustom.html

Comment: @MartinSmith If I can get permission to do that I will try it!

Comment: @clifton_h select * from SSISDB.catalog.customized_logging_levels pulls same error and I do not see it on itellisense, so it must not exist